# ¿Cómo imprimo sólo el máximo valor en un ciclo for?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Debo hacer un programa para calcular el máximo común divisor de dos números, y decidí hacerlo con un ciclo for. El problema es que en mi código se imprimen todos los números que cumplen con los requisitos.

```
a=int(raw_input('Ingresa tu primer numero: '))
b=int(raw_input('Ingresa tu segundo numero: '))

#Separaremos dos casos
#Primero, cuando a sea mayor a b

if a>b:
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if a % i == 0.:   #Aca vemos si hay algun numero i que al dividir a a no deje resto
            if b !=0:     #Aca tomamos la posibilad de que b sea distinto de cero
                if b % i == 0.:  #Y aca vemos si i tambien es divisor de b
                    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es:'
                    print i
if b == 0:  #Aca tomamos la posibilidad de que b sea igual a cero
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es: ', a

#Ahora cuando b sea mayor a a

if b>a:
    for i in range(1,b+1):
        if b % i == 0.:
            if a !=0:
                if a % i == 0.:
                    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', b, ' y ', a, ' son:'
                    print i
if a == 0:
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', b, ' y ', a, ' es: ', b
```

Por ejemplo, cuando ingreso los números 20 y 10, me imprime

```
Maximo comun divisor para 20 y 10 es:
1
Maximo comun divisor para 20 y 10 es:
2
Maximo comun divisor para 20 y 10 es:
5
Maximo comun divisor para 20 y 10 es:
10
```

Y sólo quiero que imprima el número más grande (en este caso el 10). Agradecería mucho su ayuda!!

Comment: Guarda el valor en una variable e imprímela **despues** de salir del bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
a=int(raw_input('Ingresa tu primer numero: '))
b=int(raw_input('Ingresa tu segundo numero: '))

#Separaremos dos casos
#Primero, cuando a sea mayor a b

max_divisor = 1

if a>b:
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if a % i == 0.:   #Aca vemos si hay algun numero i que al dividir a a no deje resto
            if b !=0:     #Aca tomamos la posibilad de que b sea distinto de cero
                if b % i == 0.:  #Y aca vemos si i tambien es divisor de b
                    if i > max_divisor:
                        max_divisor = i

if b == 0:  #Aca tomamos la posibilidad de que b sea igual a cero
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es: ', a

#Ahora cuando b sea mayor a a

if b>a:
    for i in range(1,b+1):
        if b % i == 0.:
            if a !=0:
                if a % i == 0.:
                    if i > max_divisor:
                        max_divisor = i

if a == 0:
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', b, ' y ', a, ' es: ', b

print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es:'
print max_divisor
```

Ojo, en b == 0 0 y a == 0 deberías hacer un sys.exit() para terminar el programa y no ejecutar el ultimo print

Comment: Funcionó demasiado bien!! Gracias igual por la observación de b == 0 y a == 0, no lo había pensado.

Answer (score 2):

Por aportar otra solución (*y un poco más de ruido*):

```
def mcd(a,b):
    return next((i for i in range(min(a,b),0,-1) if a%i==0 and b%i==0), 0)
```

Comment: Yo sólo entré a esta pregunta por "ese ruido" ;)

Comment: Muy buen oído tienes después de tanto tiempo :)

Answer (score 1):

En el código que tienes se pintan todos los números que cumplen la condición porque recorre i veces el bucle for.

```
if a>b:
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if a % i == 0.:   #Aca vemos si hay algun numero i que al     dividir a a no deje resto
            if b !=0:     #Aca tomamos la posibilad de que b sea     distinto de cero
                if b % i == 0.:  #Y aca vemos si i tambien es divisor de b
                    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es:'
                    print i
```

Tendrías que comprobar por cada vuelta del bucle si se trata del mayor número, y podría hacerse con una condición y aun auxiliar, y mostrando por pantalla después del bucle

```
if b % i == 0.:  #Y aca vemos si i tambien es divisor de b
    if i > aux:
        aux = i
```

aux lo iniciamos a cero. Y después del bucle for pintamos el mayor

```
print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es:'
print aux
```

Lo mismo pasa con a>b como b>a, así que sería cambiar en ambos bucles y ya no tendría que salirte todos, sólo los mayores.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer y que se me ocurre para calcular el mcd de manera eficiente es usar el algoritmo de euclides:

```
while x:
     x, y = y%x, x

mcd = y
```

Answer (score 0):

con una variable auxiliar puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
aux = 0
if a>b:
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        if a % i == 0.:   #Aca vemos si hay algun numero i que al dividir a a no deje resto
            if b !=0:     #Aca tomamos la posibilad de que b sea distinto de cero
                if b % i == 0.:  #Y aca vemos si i tambien es divisor de b
                    aux = i
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es:' 
    print aux

if b == 0:  #Aca tomamos la posibilidad de que b sea igual a cero
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', a, ' y ', b, ' es: ', a

#Ahora cuando b sea mayor a a

if b>a:
    for i in range(1,b+1):
        if b % i == 0.:
            if a !=0:
                if a % i == 0.:
                    aux = i
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', b, ' y ', a, ' son:'
    print aux
if a == 0:
    print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', b, ' y ', a, ' es: ', b
```

Comment: Inicializa aux a 1, no se puede dividir por 0

Comment: tienes razon pero en este caso no se esta usando aux como divisor, aunque seria muchisimo mejor para no tener un resultado de cero en caso que no entre en el ciclo. buena observacion

Answer (score 0):

```
#una forma interesante de calcular el mcd es usando el algorito de Euclides
#sea a y b numeros naturales > 0 entonces el mcd se puede calcular de la siguiente manera:
a = 20
b = 30
c = a % b
while c > 0:
    a = b
    b = c
    c = a % b
print('el mcd es ', b)
```

Comment: Definitivamente es un código más fácil que el mio jaja. Gracias por el comentario, lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Para mi deberías guardarla en una variable extra... X ejemplo max.... Y un condicional que no la sobreescriba si el valor q ya contiene la variable es mayor al q se está x reescribir...y fuera de los bucle imprimir max...... Con eso debería bastar. Suerte

Comment: Hola @JanetPerez, bienvenida a SOes,  puedes agregar un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Para mi la mejor opcion es:

```
a=int(raw_input('Ingresa tu primer numero: '))
b=int(raw_input('Ingresa tu segundo numero: '))

sa = set([i for i in xrange(1,a+1) if not a%i]+[0])
sb = set([i for i in xrange(1,b+1) if not b%i]+[0])

c = max(sa & sb)
print 'Maximo comun divisor para ', b, ' y ', a, ' es: ', c
```